# jQuery effects aren't working after I try to preload images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using code from this website to preload images: http://smallenvelop.com/display-loading-icon-page-loads-completely/
How come when I choose to preload all "img" in index.html with:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
       $(function(){
           $('.images').imgPreload()
       })
</script>
```

then my jumping effect does not work on the images cindy.png and cindy_jump.png.

Here are my main files:

script.js

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Wait for window load
  $(window).load(function() {
    // Animate loader off screen
    $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");;
  });
  //cindy jump effect
  $('.cindy').on('click', function() {
    $('.cindy').slideUp(1000, function() {
      $(this).find('img').html();
      $('.cursor').css('display', 'none');
      $('.cursor_jump').css('display', 'inline');
      $('.cindy_jump').slideDown(1000);
      $('#caption').replaceWith("<h3 id='caption'>Or not if you prefer.</h3>");
    });
  });

  //reverse jump
  $('.cindy_jump').on('click', function() {
    $('.cindy_jump').slideUp(1000, function() {
      $(this).find('img').html();
      $('.cursor_jump').css('display', 'none');
      $('.cursor').css('display', 'inline');
      $('.cindy').slideDown(1000);
      $('#caption').replaceWith("<h3 id='caption'>See me jump.</h3>");
    });
  });
});
```

index.html

```html
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  <script type='text/javascript' src='loadImg.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
      $('.images').imgPreload()
    })
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Cindy Liu</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="se-pre-con"></div>
  <div class="opening" style="text-align: center">
    <div class="hover-image">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <img class="cindy" src="cindy.PNG">
        <img class="cursor" src="cursor.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <p class="blurb">I'm Cindy</p>
      <h3 id="caption">See me jump</h3>
      <h6 class="down"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <img class="cindy_jump" src="cindy_jump.PNG">
      <img class="cursor_jump" src="cursor.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="images">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img src="mabel.JPG" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="butterfly.JPG" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="shanghai.JPG" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="me.JPG" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="waffle.JPG" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img src="chinchilla.JPG" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="school.JPG" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="ocean.JPG" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="tennis.JPG" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="kayak.JPG" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

stylesheet.css

```css
.no-js #loader {
  display: none;
}
.js #loader {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 0;
}
.se-pre-con {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: url(images/images/loader-64x/Preloader_5.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
}
```

loadImg.js

```js
(function() {
  (function($) {
    return $.fn.imgPreload = function(options) {
      var delay_completion, i, image_stack, placeholder_stack, replace, settings, spinner_stack, src, x, _i, _len;
      settings = {
        fake_delay: 10,
        animation_duration: 1000,
        spinner_src: 'images/images/loader-64x/Preloader_5.gif'
      };
      if (options) {
        $.extend(settings, options);
      }
      image_stack = [];
      placeholder_stack = [];
      spinner_stack = [];
      window.delay_completed = false;
      delay_completion = function() {
        var x, _i, _len, _results;
        window.delay_completed = true;
        _results = [];
        for (_i = 0, _len = image_stack.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
          x = image_stack[_i];
          _results.push($(x).attr('data-load-after-delay') === 'true' ? (replace(x), $(x).removeAttr('data-load-after-delay')) : void 0);
        }
        return _results;
      };
      setTimeout(delay_completion, settings.fake_delay);
      this.each(function() {
        var $image, $placeholder, $spinner_img, offset_left, offset_top;
        $image = $(this);
        offset_top = $image.offset().top;
        offset_left = $image.offset().left;
        $spinner_img = $('<img>');
        $placeholder = $('<img>').attr({
          src: 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABA\
                IABAP///wAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=='
        });
        $placeholder.attr({
          width: $image.attr('width')
        });
        $placeholder.attr({
          height: $image.attr('height')
        });
        spinner_stack.push($spinner_img);
        placeholder_stack.push($placeholder);
        image_stack.push($image.replaceWith($placeholder));
        $('body').append($spinner_img);
        $spinner_img.css({
          position: 'absolute'
        });
        $spinner_img.css('z-index', 9999);
        $spinner_img.load(function() {
          $(this).css({
            left: (offset_left + $placeholder.width() / 2) - $(this).width() / 2
          });
          return $(this).css({
            top: (offset_top + $placeholder.height() / 2) - $(this).height() / 2
          });
        });
        return $spinner_img.attr({
          src: settings.spinner_src
        });
      });
      i = 0;
      for (_i = 0, _len = image_stack.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        x = image_stack[_i];
        x.attr({
          no: i++
        });
        src = x.attr('src');
        x.attr({
          src: ''
        });
        x.load(function() {
          if (window.delay_completed) {
            return replace(this);
          } else {
            return $(this).attr('data-load-after-delay', true);
          }
        });
        x.attr({
          src: src
        });
      }
      replace = function(image) {
        var $image, no_;
        $image = $(image);
        no_ = $image.attr('no');
        placeholder_stack[no_].replaceWith($image);
        spinner_stack[no_].fadeOut(settings.animation_duration / 2, function() {
          return $(this).remove();
        });
        return $image.fadeOut(0).fadeIn(settings.animation_duration);
      };
      return this;
    };
  })(jQuery);
}).call(this);
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are referring 2 different versions of `jquery` `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`
and
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Remove the earlier one as it is older version.. That should do the job!

Comment: Thanks for that catch Guruprasad. However, now my cindy_jump.png is initially visible when I want it to be hidden at first, and the jQuery effects are still not working.

Comment: have the css settings changed so that cindy_jump image is not displayed
and display using jquery

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the cindy and cindy_jump css. I actually do have it initially not displayed. These effects are only not working after I added the preloading

Comment: .cindy {
 margin-top: 30vh;
 height: 250px;
 display: inline;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

.cindy:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}

.cindy_jump {
 height: 225px;
 width: auto;
 margin-bottom: 150px;
 margin-top: 20vh;
 display: none;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

.cindy_jump:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}
.cursor {
 margin-top: 30vh;
 height: 20px;
}

.cursor_jump {
 margin-top: 20vh;
 height: 20px;
 display: none;
}

Comment: @clue11 I suggest you to create a **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)** to narrate the problem properly!!